# HTML/JavaScript Tic Tac Toe with a 2D array

Tags: javascript, html, multidimensional-array

I am fairly new to HTML5 and JavaScript and i am trying to learn game programming. So i decided to try to make a Tic Tac Toe game with the board being rendered from a 2D array. I set it up so it changes color with the CSS:hover but now i'm just trying to make each box change to the color red when it is clicked and this is where i am stuck.

I'm not looking for anyone to finish my code for me its just I am trying to take things slow(ish) and i would like to figure those out on my own. My question is how do i make each box change color when you click? Currently i have each element of the array create a  and i then positioned them and added a addEventListener to their class. My code KIND-OF works in the sense that the very last element changes color when you click it, but none of the others do.

Here's my code.

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Tic Tac Toe</title>

<style>

#stage
{
    position: relative;
}

.cell
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
}

.cell:hover
{
    background-color: blue;
}

</style>

<div id="stage"></div>

<script>

//get a reference to the stage
var stage = document.querySelector("#stage");

//the 2d array that defines the board
var board = 
[
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0]
];

//the size of each cell
var SIZE = 100;

//the space between each cell
var SPACE = 10;

//display the array
var ROWS = board.length;
var COLUMNS = board[0].length;

for(var row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
{
    for(var column = 0; column < COLUMNS; column++)
    {
        //create a div HTML element called cell
        var cell = document.createElement("div");

        //set its CSS class to cell
        cell.setAttribute("class", "cell");

        //add the div HTML element to the stage
        stage.appendChild(cell);

        //position the cell
        cell.style.top = row * (SIZE + SPACE) + "px";
        cell.style.left = column * (SIZE + SPACE) + "px";
    }
}

cell.addEventListener("click", clickHandler, false);

function clickHandler()
{
    cell.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    console.log("worked");
}

</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't use a 2D array. I'd just use one array with nine elements to represent the board. If I'm feeling particularly esoteric I might have the board be represented as an integer between 0 and 19682, representing the game board in base three...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Yeah, a single array would probably be easier, but I was curious if i could make a 2D array work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's one simple mistake, you bound the click handler outside your loop. When you move it inside the loop, you'll need to change `cell.style` to `this.style`, because `cell` will reference the last value of the variable after the loop instead of the current cell.

It's also worth noting that your current code is not compatible with Internet Explorer 8 and below because of the `addEventListener` method. It is recommended that if you plan on manipulating elements on your page, you use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), which makes these compatibility issues irrelevant to some degree (in this case you would need the v1.x.x version of jquery, since v2.x.x has dropped support for IE 8)

```
var stage = document.querySelector("#stage");

//the 2d array that defines the board
var board = [
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0]
];

//the size of each cell
var SIZE = 100;

//the space between each cell
var SPACE = 10;

//display the array
var ROWS = board.length;
var COLUMNS = board[0].length;

for(var row = 0; row < ROWS; row++){
    for(var column = 0; column < COLUMNS; column++){
        //create a div HTML element called cell
        var cell = document.createElement("div");

        //set its CSS class to cell
        cell.setAttribute("class", "cell");

        //add the div HTML element to the stage
        stage.appendChild(cell);

        //position the cell
        cell.style.top = row * (SIZE + SPACE) + "px";
        cell.style.left = column * (SIZE + SPACE) + "px";

        //handle click
        cell.addEventListener("click", clickHandler, false);
    }
}

function clickHandler(){
    this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    console.log("worked");
}
```

Comment: Also, thanks for the note on IE8 and jQuery. I am new to JavaScript and programming in general so i have not yet got my hands on jQuery but i will make it a priority too. Thanks!

Comment: @Iqbalhossain The fiddle was deleted by JSFiddle, I have no idea what was in it at this point, so I removed the link. The relevant code is still in the answer though, the fiddle was only showing OP's code with slight modifications I believe.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is simple :

- First register the event for each element (so it is in the loop)
- Use the argument *event* in your event fonction

So I've got this :

```
//get a reference to the stage
var stage = document.querySelector("#stage");

//the 2d array that defines the board
var board = 
[
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0]
];

//the size of each cell
var SIZE = 100;

//the space between each cell
var SPACE = 10;

//display the array
var ROWS = board.length;
var COLUMNS = board[0].length;

for(var row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
{
    for(var column = 0; column < COLUMNS; column++)
    {
        //create a div HTML element called cell
        var cell = document.createElement("div");

        //set its CSS class to cell
        cell.setAttribute("class", "cell");

        //add the div HTML element to the stage
        stage.appendChild(cell);

        //position the cell
        cell.style.top = row * (SIZE + SPACE) + "px";
        cell.style.left = column * (SIZE + SPACE) + "px";
        cell.addEventListener("click", clickHandler, false);
    }
}


function clickHandler(event)
{
    console.log(event);
    event.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    console.log("worked");
}
```

Here is my test : http://jsfiddle.net/DSNLR/

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way:
1. put

```
cell.addEventListener("click", clickHandler, false);
```

into the loop, because each cell should have it's own listener.
2. handler should work with appropriate cell, but not with some general CELL

```
function clickHandler()
{
    this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    console.log("worked");
}
```

If you want to increase performance, then you should listen to parent element (which contains all cells) and dispatch event.

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about JavaScript, but something about Java. I think the

`cell.addEventListener("click", clickHandler, false);`

has to be inside the for-loops like that:

```
for(var row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
{
  for(var column = 0; column < COLUMNS; column++)
  {
    //create a div HTML element called cell
    var cell = document.createElement("div");

    //do your stuff here

    //now the event listener
    cell.addEventListener("click", clickHandler, false);
  }
}
```

That should work. You only added it to the last cell.